# The Hockey Puck and Combat Carl in Toy Story

Tags: character, toy-story

Was the Hockey Puck in the first *Toy Story* movie only put in as a gag or only for Mr. Potato Head to say "What are you looking at, you hockey puck?" as we don't see it anymore after that. Also, why is Combat Carl in the first *Toy Story* movie different from the Combat Carl seen in *Toy Story of Terror*?

Comment: Here is the scene in the question, for reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_WiwOojDTrs

Comment: should this be divided into 2 separate questions?

Comment: @miltonaut yes...probably :)

Answer (score 5):

Regarding the hockey puck reference: definitely.

In ***Toy Story***, Mr. Potato Head is voiced by famous insult comedian **Don "Mr. Warmth" Rickles**. In the early days of his career, "hockey puck" was one of Rickles' signature insults, typically used to lambast ill-behaved audience members.

[image]

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_Rickles)